# Завершение метода дочернего класса из базового

Tags: c++

Есть код

```
    #include <iostream.h>

class Base
{
    public:
    virtual void func ()=0; 
    virtual ~Base () {}
};

class Manager
{
    Base* OBJ;
    public:
    void Remove (Base* obj)
    {
        delete obj;
        OBJ=NULL;
    }
    void Loop (Base* obj)
    {
        OBJ=obj;

        while (1)
        {
            if (OBJ!=NULL)
                OBJ->func ();
        }
    }
}Mangr;

class Derived:public Base
{
    int a;
    public:
    void func ()
    {
        if (a>=100)
            Mangr.Remove(this);

        std::cout<<a++<<'\n';
    }   
    Derived ()
    {
        a=0;
    }
};

int main ()
{
    Mangr.Loop (new Derived ());

    return 0;
}
```

Возможно ли как-то завершить метод func класса Derived не находясь в нем? Когда срабатывает условие и в классе Magaer происходит освобождение памяти, все что ниже метода func должно отброситься. Без использования return в func, т.е. все на уровне Base или Manager классов.

Comment: Лучше как-то иначе спроектировать классы. Я более 15-ти лет программирую на плюсах. Очень многое повидал. Приходилось даже изучать исходники boost'а. Но даже я не понимаю, что должен делать этот код...

Answer (score 2):

Нельзя "завершить метод наполовине". Можно завершить поток, в котором он выполняется. Это "отбросит все что ниже метода func".

Работа с потоками не имеет ничего общего с наследованием (это ортогональные понятия) и вообще с кодом в вашем вопросе.

Для "отбрасывания" нужно убить поток, в котором вызван ваш loop (плохой вариант).

Или использовать какой-то признак для прекращения работы - bool со спин-блокировкой, auto reset event-ы, устанавливать его при "чистке памяти" и проверять в `func`, потом дожидаться завершения итерации (по еще одному признаку) и только после этого чистить память.

Но даже в этом случае код, вызывающий `loop` должен получать какой-то намек, что цикл завершился - потому что он продолжит выполнение.

Answer (score 0):

Нет, невозможно. Вы не можете насильно завершить выполняющийся метод. Для корректного завершения метода метод должен сотрудничать.

Для вашего примера, пусть класс `Manager` проверяет возвращаемое значение `func`, и в зависимости от этого продолжает или нет свою работу.

Потенциально возможным методом нелокального перехода мог бы быть выброс исключения. Но так делать не следует: цель исключения — не управление потоком программы, а информирование об действительно исключительных ситуациях.

Answer (score 0):

Я ничего не понял в вашем коде, но неважно.
Кидайте исключение в классе Manager.
Вот:

```
void Remove (Base* obj)
{
  delete obj;
  OBJ=NULL;
  throw std::exception();
}

void Loop (Base* obj)
{
    OBJ=obj;

    try {
        while (1)
        {
            if (OBJ!=NULL)
                OBJ->func ();
        }
    } catch ( std::exception& ex ) {
    }
}
```